# Error Django smart-select: /smart_selects/widgets.py in <module>, line 4

Tags: django, select, static, admin

i've a problem, like a title.
I've tried to install smart_selects in my project Django, but does not work.
I followed the readme in https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects... but the error is:

> No module named admin_static
>   Request Method: GET
>   Request URL:    http://***.com/panel/schedevendorcomplete/add/1/Basic/
>   Django Version: 1.2.7
>   Exception Type: ImportError
>   Exception Value:
>
>   No module named admin_static
>   Exception Location: /var/www/website/smart_selects/widgets.py in , line 4
>   Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
>   Python Version: 2.7.3
>   Python Path:    ['/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/var/www/vhosts/**.com', '/var/www/vhosts/**.com/website']
>   Server time:    sab, 6 Apr 2013 20:50:04 +0200
>   Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response
>                           request.path_info) ...
>   ▶ Local vars
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in resolve
>               for pattern in self.url_patterns: ...
>   ▶ Local vars
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in _get_url_patterns
>           patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module) ...
>   ▶ Local vars
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in _get_urlconf_module
>               self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name) ...
>   ▶ Local vars
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py in import_module
>       _*import*_(name) ...
>   ▶ Local vars
>   /var/www/vhosts/tuttoricevimenti.com/website/urls.py in 
>   admin.autodiscover() ...
>   ▶ Local vars
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/_*init*_.py in autodiscover
>               import_module('%s.admin' % app) ...
>   ▶ Local vars
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py in import_module
>       _*import*_(name) ...
>   ▶ Local vars
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/admin.py in 
>   admin.site.register(Group, GroupAdmin) ...
>   ▶ Local vars
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py in register
>               validate(admin_class, model) ...
>   ▶ Local vars
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/validation.py in validate
>       models.get_apps() ...
>   ▶ Local vars
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py in get_apps
>           self._populate() ...
>   ▶ Local vars
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py in _populate
>                       self.load_app(app_name) ...
>   ▶ Local vars
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py in load_app
>               models = import_module('.models', app_name) ...
>   ▶ Local vars
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py in import_module
>       _*import*_(name) ...
>   ▶ Local vars
>   /var/wwww/vhosts/***.com/gazzettadelpopolo/models.py in 
>   from website.smart_selects.db_fields import GroupedForeignKey ...
>   ▶ Local vars
>   /var/wwww/vhosts/***.com/website/smart_selects/db_fields.py in 
>   import form_fields ...
>   ▶ Local vars
>   /var/www/website/smart_selects/form_fields.py in 
>   from smart_selects.widgets import ChainedSelect ...
>   ▶ Local vars
>   /var/www/website/smart_selects/widgets.py in 
>   from django.contrib.admin.templatetags.admin_static import static ...
>   ▶ Local vars

I do not know where I'm wrong, I'm not very familiar with django.

What could be causing this?

Tnx

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is in your **settings.py** file. When says: "**No module named admin_static**" means that you didn't installed it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your django version , then you can install django-smart-selects

make sure your django version is the latest one or from this range

1.8.5   , 1.8.6  or  1.9